# How do I merge 2 remote branches?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to pull from a remote branch, and git says it is gonna be a merge, so i did not quite  understand this git message, how can i enter the commit message and complete the pull process?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is git’s way of saying there are differences in your commit history so both the differences would be merged together if you pull.

Depending on your work and workflow this could be huge or just few files.

While merging there may occur merge conflicts as well, if so you would have to review them and resolve the conflicts.

**As for your question**

you can enter the commit message on the window provided. That is a vim editor so

- press `a` to go into append mode
- enter the commit message there
- press `esc` to exit the append mode
- press `wq` ( write and quit )

Which will initiate the merge process

If there are no conflicts everything should go smoothly.

Comment: It's not [`nano`](https://www.nano-editor.org/screenshots.php), it's vim. The commands to input text, save and exit are completely different.

Comment: how do i enter that commit message though? i know what it is asking me for.. problem is where and how do i enter that input?

Comment: The screenshot that you posted is actually VIM editor. When you are exactly at that window. Press the key  `a` - which will enable you to input your message there, type what ever you intend there. Then press `esc` which will exit from the append mode and you’ll be able to provide commands again. So when you are there press `wq` which will exit the editor after saving your message.

Answer (score 1):

The git has opened you a vim editor to set the commit message. You just need to write something (optionally) and then exit the vim :)

To exit vim you need to press ESC, then `:wq`

[image]

Comment: To write something in `vim` one needs to enter insert mode. The rest is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your local branch and remote branch have diverged (this can be the case if someone else pushed changes to the remote branch and you also did modification on the local branch for example).

You can do a `git merge` in your local branch (this will merge the remote in your local branch) and if you want to add a message, you can modify the merge commit message.

Here is more documentation:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches